# How to create windows forms Form from non UI thread

Tags: c#, winforms

I use code similar to this, but this is not working, becouse client subscibe callback action is running in non UI thread. How can I schedule callback action to windows forms UI thread?

```cs
    internal static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        private static void Main()
        {
            Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            using (var context = new ProgramApplicationContext())
            {
                Application.Run(context);
            }
        }
    }

    internal class ProgramApplicationContext : ApplicationContext
    {
        public ProgramApplicationContext()
        {
            ...
            _client.subscribe("event", message => {
                var form = new CommunicationForm();
                form.Show();
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: You'll probably need to use Invoke to invoke it back to the UI thread.  Test for Control.InvokeRequired() then use Control.Invoke() and the form should be displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [SynchronizationContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.send?view=net-7.0) to create the form on the UI thread.

```
public ProgramApplicationContext()
{
    ...
    var ctx = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    _client.subscribe("event", message => {
        ctx.Send(state => {
            var form = new CommunicationForm();
            form.Show();
        }, null);
    });
}
```